# Can I open Xpage app from Notes Browser Plugin Workspace?

Tags: xpages

I have both notes native apps and Xpages apps.
When I tried to open Xpages app from Notes Browser Plugin workspace, it opened just notes native view(like basic client).
I changed launch option like below. Both didn't work.

- "When opened in the Notes Client" -> "Open designated XPage(Standard Client).
- "When opened in a browser" -> "Open designated XPage"

Can I open app as Xpage when I'm using Notes Browser Plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paul writes: if you want XPiNC, then you can't.

We use short trick to launch XPages application in browser even from workspace.
Use this PostOpen database script:

```
Sub Postopen(Source As Notesuidatabase)
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim url As String

    url = ... ' use some parameter to get application url (profile?)
    If url = "" Then url = "https://your base web url/" + Replace( Source.Database.FilePath, "\\", "/" )
    ws.Urlopen url
    Source.Close

    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    Print Erl, Error
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

This will open XPages application from basic client.

Disclaimer: PostOpen event is skipped in case user follows a doclink or uses "Application/Goto" to open specific view.

Comment: Great trick!  Do you do anything in case user open app using doc link?

Comment: @satohiro Do the same with QueryOpen in form events. Instead of `Source.Close` use `Continue = False`

Answer (score 3):

Notes browser plugin is effectively the basic client. The basic client can't display composite applications or XPiNC applications, so the Notes settings won't work. And because the browser plugin is effectively a wrapper for the basic client, the "When opened in browser" option is not used, because it's in the basic client wrapped within the client.

One option is to use another "workspace" like this project on OpenNTF http://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Application%20Catalog.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I understand that. And the option seems very useful.